# CGI script having trouble sending emojis characters from database

Tags: mysql, perl, email, cgi, emoji

I am storing emojis in a  MySQL database expressed in UTF8 Bytes, like `"\xf0\x9f\x98\x80"`, which is the Unicode character `U+1F600 GRINNING FACE`

It is fine if I copy and paste it in and test it like this

```
print MAIL "Subject: \xf0\x9f\x98\x80\n";
```

It works and sends me the emoji.

But if I tell the script to get it from the database and plug it in like this:

```
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n";
```

It will give me the subject: \xf0\x9f\x98\x80

What do I need to do?  I thought if I was storing it in bytes it would see it as plain text and it would work.

Comment: That's not a valid subject. You need to RFC1342 encode that.

Comment: Please explain how I would do that.

Comment: @tadman while that might be true, it's not what's going wrong here. Not yet, at least.

Comment: Can you please [edit] and give more details about what you are trying to do? I think you are trying to send an email, but I'm not sure. Please include the top of your program (where it says `use strict` and `use warnings`), and at least the part with `open MAIL` (which should really be `open my $fh, ...`), both with a few lines around them. It would also be interesting to see the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of the database table you are using, and possibly an example row. Encoding is not trivial if you are not familiar with it, and many things can go wrong.

Comment: @tadman: That is complete nonsense. RFC-1342 is titled *"Representation of Non-ASCII Text in Internet Message Headers"* but the OP's issue has nothing to do with the internet at all. This is purely about static character encoding, and the solution lies only in making sure that every component of the dialogue is working with the same encoding. If you were trying to impress someone then you have failed badly.

Comment: @tadman Sorry, yes I am trying to email the emoji in the subject line.  It will email perfectly as an emoji if I hard code it in to the subject like so:  `"Subject: \xf0\x9f\x98\x80\n";` but when I try to pass the emoji in a variable from the database it is received in my email account as simply \xf0\x9f\x98\x80

Comment: @Borodin This is an email message, so RFC1342 absolutely applies. You can't slam arbitrary UTF-8 in your "Subject" line. It must be 7-bit ASCII with the proper `=utf8=...` encoding or most email clients and many email servers will flat-out reject it. Solving the UTF8 problem is only half the issue.

Comment: @tadman: Ah, I misunderstood the RFC. *Internet Message* says HTTP, SMTP etc. messages and not email messages. Also, subsequent page headers refer to *Non-ASCII Mail Headers* which is a different thing. Note that RFC-1342 has been obsoleted twice, and the latest document seems to be [RFC-2047](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047). Finally, a lot depends on what command-line tool is at the other end of the `MAIL` file handle what must be sent to it.

Comment: @Borodin It's referred to as RFC1342 encoding, as the basic principle hasn't changed, but as with most, like the venerable RFC822, now RFC5322, it's understood that it means "latest revision of X".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems most likely that you have added the value to the database wrongly.

If you use Perl code and write the string `'\xf0\x9f\x98\x80'` to the database (note the single quotes) then you will get exactly the symptoms you describe. Your database will contain the sixteen-character ASCII string `\xf0\x9f\x98\x80` and it will be displayed as such.

You shouldn't be involved with the UTF-8  encoded bytes; it is far better to specify the Unicode code point either by name or number

All of these produce the same Perl UTF-8-encoded string

```
$s = "\N{U+1F600}";
$s = "\N{GRINNING FACE}";
$s = "\x{1F600}";
```

The corresponding  encoded bytes are irrelevant to the programmer, but if you must you can use the `Encode` module like this

```
use Encode 'decode_utf8';

$s = decode_utf8 "\xf0\x9f\x98\x80";
```

Another way is to enter the character directly into your code. You will need `use utf8` to indicate to the compiler that the source contains non-ASCII UTF-8-encoded characters, like this

```
use utf8;

$s = "";
```

All of these assignments to `$s` will produce exactly the same result, and the values will compare as being equal using `eq`

On the database side you need a MySQL column with a *four-byte UTF-8 character set*, for instance

```
column VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
```

Note that the character set *must* be `utf8mb4` as if you use the earlier `utf8` then you would be restricted to three-byte encoding, whereas emoji characters are all four bytes

Comment: @topedge: Please would you comment on whether my answer has been useful and how you applied it. I doubt that this is the complete solution.

Comment: It was useful to me. However, I don't understand why a MySQL search for "dog" doesn't match things like "dög".